# Fragment weird crash when coming back to portrait mode

Tags: android, android-fragments, crash, back-stack, android-appcompat

My app is having one MainActivity and four Fragments in which 2nd Fragment contains master & detail layout for landscape mode.

App Flow(Landscape mode) - MainActivity-> Fragment 1 -> Fragment 2 | Fragment 3 -> Fragment 4

App is crashing when i am coming back on 2nd fragment to portrait mode.

FYI: using actionbar-compat lib.

Crash Log:

```
01-09 03:42:01.479: E/InputEventSender(18767): Exception dispatching finished signal.
01-09 03:42:01.479: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18767): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
01-09 03:42:01.509: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18767): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090070 (abc.fragmentdemo:id/detail_layout) for fragment Fragment3{41e0def0 #0 id=0x7f090070 detailsFrag}
01-09 03:42:01.509: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18767):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
01-09 03:42:01.509: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18767):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-09 03:42:01.509: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18767):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
01-09 03:42:01.509: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18767):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1884)
01-09 03:42:01.509: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18767):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1514)
01-09 03:42:01.509: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18767):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
01-09 03:42:01.509: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18767):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-09 03:42:01.509: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18767):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:764)
01-09 03:42:01.509: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18767):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1516)
01-09 03:42:01.509: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18767):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:488)
01-09 03:42:01.509: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18767):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:179)
01-09 03:42:01.509: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18767):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onBackPressed(ActionBarActivity.java:250)
```

DemoApp Code

[Download Zip](https://github.com/bipinvaylu/FragmentDemo/archive/master.zip)

git : https://github.com/bipinvaylu/FragmentDemo.git